# Resolution independence - why its not easy?

Tags: resolution

Why doesn't the OS just keep everything in the same physical size when you change resolution? Its true that sometimes a little blurring or pixelation occur, but when there is no large difference in resolutions (such as 1920X1080 vs 1920X1200) these effects are minimal.

However what would happen instead when you change resolutions is that everything will shrink or expand. This is almost never what the user had in mind.

So why do operating systems behave in this weird way?

Comment: I'm not too sure about this but I believe the operating system does not actually have direct control over actual pixels of the monitor. The OS (the display drivers) just tells the monitor what to display at what resolution (not necessarily the correct one of the monitor) and the monitor's firmware itself is what draws them in sometimes oddly scaled ways. I think they are designed like this to prevent just a black screen if a driver is uninstalled or corrupted; it can display oddly scaled (but better than no display) if a driver isn't using the correct resolution for some reason.

Comment: Probably a [ux.se] question, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Resolution Independence works by completely changing the game, you're no longer dealing with pixels, but are now dealing with vectors, the entire rendering pipeline has to be completely rewritten to support vector graphics, every single UI resource has to be recreated in a vector format (like SVG), which takes a lot of time and energy.

now for the REALLY difficult part, you have to draw your UI using those resources at no resolution at all, you simply stack and arrange the contents in the order it's supposed to be stacked, now you need to render this actual stack to the monitor, which could be any resolution, the text has to be big enough but not too big, the buttons have to be big enough but not to big as well, you have to account for aspect ratio, screen resolution, PPI, actual, physical screen size, etc.

and there aren't even any universal ways to query the display about it's actual physical size (AFAIK)

if any one of those variables isn't taken into account, or even worse is given inaccurate information, your UI will be completely broken to the end user.